# Checking for app installation in XCUITest

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, xcuitest

I am trying to find a robust way to check if an app was downloaded via MDM and is available on the device. I would think the below would work:

```
let authenticatorApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.microsoft.azureauthenticator")
XCTAssert(authenticatorApp.waitForExistence(timeout: 60))
```

However this seems to always time out, even if the app is installed.

The only way I can think of requires checking the existence of an URL scheme, but I don't think that would work with all apps since some don't have one.

Is there any better way?

UPDATE: I tried do-catch of launch(), but it seems it doesn't throw an exception and always fails the test, so this won't work. Also I tried watching the state in a for-loop (with a sleep) but that didn't work either.

UPDATE2: I am not even able to get this working with the canOpenURL() route. I get "This app is not allowed to query" even when I add an entry in the "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes", and I heard this broke on some version of iOS (13?)

Comment: The only answers I'm finding require the app to have a URL scheme and using that.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to get that to work on iOS 14.3. Let me know if you were able to, and if so let me know what iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for **URL scheme** with `canOpenURL:` function. **But remember!** you can't check for a dynamic list of schemes! Because from iOS 9+ you must whitelist any URL schemes your App wants to query in `Info.plist` under the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key (an array of strings):

[image: preview]

The reason of this limitation is to restrict apps to track user's installed apps and the AppStoreConnect may ask you why you think you want to open all these schemes in the review process.

#### Check Asynchronously

Also you can use `open:options:completionHandler:` method and check inside the `completionHandler`. This method is more likely to be a successful try in iOS 14 but don't forget that it is an async task!